# Decapitated Zombie heads active or dead?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Can a beheaded zombie still be active? Clara and the governor had zombie heads, but then how come when Michone decapitates a zombie all parts are officially dead?

Comment: Weaponized in [Sluggy Freelance](http://sluggy.wikia.com/wiki/Zombie_Head_on_a_Stick).  And, of course, it's useful [in many other ways](http://www.sluggy.com/comics/archives/daily/20090224).

Comment: Most of the times that Michonne attacks the head, she slices through the skull, which would "kill" the zombie. Most of the other times, we are not shown specifically that the zombie was fully "killed", but since the head can't actively pursue anyone, it is probably just considered a non-active-threat and ignored.

Answer (score 2):

**A zombie whose head has been removed but whose brain has not been destroyed, is inactive but not necessarily completely dead. It is simply unable to do very much besides moan and gnash its teeth impotently.**

- The body falls down dead and while the head may continue to make biting motions, its mobility has been completely removed.
- A zombie whose brain has been destroyed is completely dead. No activity whatsoever. This is the preferred and desired state most of the time.
- The benefit of decapitation is, and this assumes you are skilled enough to do it right, you are able to keep your weapon moving and under your control. Stabbing through the eye or chopping thru the skull has a small chance of your weapon being stuck and unable to be removed in a timely fashion.
- Clean decapitations render the body dead, and since you aren't staying around to chat with the head, wherever it falls, is where it stays, no longer a threat to you.
- This of course means if you find yourself in a place with lots of zombie heads, it wouldn't hurt to stomp them or stab them to be sure you don't roll over into a zombie mouth that is still hungering for human flesh, just unable to get it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't "officially dead." The heads can still be active, but the threat is neutralized.That is all that needs to be done. The brain controls the body. Separate the two and it cannot attack. Michonne also often cuts the heads in half, instead of just off, destroying the brain.

Comment: If you were dumb enough to put your fingers in its mouth it could still bite you. I'd say more, but as River Song says: "Spoilers."